# Efficient way of handling decimal places in floats - cause DecimalFormat and StringFormat depends on locale

Tags: android, string, kotlin, format, numbers

I have encountered a problem when handling floats in an Android application

My case regards handling decimal places in kotlin `Float`, but I think it can be applied to Java.

Let's assume that I have an `EditText` which is a `Number` field in an Android app. This way, an user can just input an integer, and by an integer I mean a whole number, not the primitive data type. It's then passed to the code as a `String` so it doesn't matter.

```
private lateinit var weightText: EditText
private lateinit var heightText: EditText
```

Let's say that the user inputs two numbers - 120 and 174.

```
weightText = findViewById(R.id.etWeight)
heightText = findViewById(R.id.etHeight)
```

Then I am making an Body Mass Index calculation on them:

```
val bmiEquals = weight.toFloat() / ((height.toFloat() / 100) * (height.toFloat() / 100))
```

Easy.

But `bmiEquals` in this case is equal to *38.73967*

Now I'd like to display the user this number with just two decimal places: *38.74*

To achieve this I do:

```
val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
val bmi2Digits = df.format(bmiEquals)
```

It was working fine in the Android emulator, but when I've tested the code on my physical device, I've encountered a problem here:

```
private fun displayResult(bmi: String) {

    when (bmi.toFloat()) {
```

I got an error cause `bmi` variable was not `38.74` but `38,74`. I have researched a bit and it seems that this is caused by locale. In some countries, you divide floating point numbers using a dot, in some others - a comma. And DecimalFormat is used to format a number to a `String`.

I know that I could just use BigDecimals here, but I wonder if there is any way to handle this case while working on `Floats`.

Honestly? I have solved this problem using a silly solution:

```
when (bmi.replace(',', '.').toFloat()) {
```

But it is bothering me so hard... ;)

Answer (score 1):

you may always check which character is an decimal separator on running device using
[`DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols#getDecimalSeparator())

Answer (score 1):

You may use DecimalFormat with a specific locale.

```kotlin
val bmiEquals = 38.73967

Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH)

val dfUS = DecimalFormat("#.##", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))
// or df.decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US)
val dfResultUS = dfUS.format(bmiEquals)
println(dfResultUS) // output: 38.74

val dfLocale = DecimalFormat("#.##")
val dfResultLocale = dfLocale.format(bmiEquals)
println(dfResultLocale) // output: 38,74
```

Answer (score 0):

try following round functionality from `import kotlin.math.round`

```
var bmi2Decimal = round(bmiEquals * 100)/100
```

bmi2Decimal is float and in this case, 100 is used to make it 2 decimal place